# Tips for finding untouched/verified cartdriges dumps (ROMs)?

Tags: emulation

As my collection of original videogame cartdriges keeps growing (8-16bit), I intend to have the games backed up for **fair use** on emulation.

However, I want to make sure the versions I'm downloading are the same versions I own, and that they're **untouched** (no hacks, no patches, no changes whatsoever) and verified. For this reason, very often I find myself not sure I'm getting the right ones.

What are the recommendations for finding these good dumps easier?

Comment: I'm aware fair emulation is on topic, but I'm not sure recommendations are not.

Comment: Recommendations for sites/games/software/etc. are explicitly off topic.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Ok, slightly changed the question context, so answers like JAL's can get here. Is it okay now?

Comment: Eh, maybe? “Any tips” questions tend to be closed as “too broad” (because every answer is equally valid and that breaks the voting system). I guess the votes will tell.

Comment: RE my close vote: You can ask about emulators all you want, including about running games through emulators, it's on-topic. It can be argued that you backed up/rom-dumped the game from your own original copy (unless you explicitly state otherwise) and thus can be supported by us. **However**, if you explicitly state that you pirated the game (or in this question's case, asking for support for pirated copies of games that you downloaded) - this is off-topic for us.

Comment: A personal way i use to get good dumps is to check against any scrapper service like Screenscraper - https://www.screenscraper.fr/ - They use hashes to identify ROMs that are known good dumps, identify them, and provide the Info and Images of the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to link to any sites due to the legal gray area this would put Stack Exchange in. I can, however, list some of the symbols used in ROM naming conventions so you can identify good/bad dumps, hacks, etc.

```
[a] Alternate
[p] Pirate
[b] Bad Dump     (avoid these, they may not work!)
[t] Trained
[f] Fixed
[T-] OldTranslation
[T+] NewerTranslation
[h] Hack
(-) Unknown Year
[o] Overdump
[!] Verified Good Dump
(M#) Multilanguage (# of Languages)
(###) Checksum
(??k) ROM Size
ZZZ_ Unclassified
(Unl) Unlicensed
```

Additional codes can be found [here](https://64bitorless.wordpress.com/rom-suffix-explanations/).

Based on your question it looks like you are looking for verified good dumps.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for verified good dumps. Thanks for the tips, they surely help!